# Codeigniter session does not work after including Controller in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I was working on a site in which on right side I am displaying some fixed type of dynamic content like `event calendar`, `login`, `register` etc. right side bar name is **`right_view.php`**
So first I was doing like this that I was sending parameters in every function of controller's  and then in my view I was accessing right side parameters by calling right view like this

```
 <?php $this->load->view('right_view');?>
```

then after login I can get my username that is stored in session.
After that I thought it is not a good approach to send parameters in every functions I just make a controller named **`right.php`** and in this controller I am passing parameters to `right_view.php` and after that in my view I  changed my code for callig righr_view like this

```
<?php include(base_url().'right');?>
```

It display right content as I do above but one changed happen that I cannot access any of session stored variable in right side bar.
Is session does not work after including controller in view?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically wanting to do a template system but going about it the wrong way. And for the record no I don't think you can (or at least should) be loading controllers into views like that.

What you want is a template file something like this:

```
<?php 
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $title);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$sidebar_content);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$main_content);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
?>
```

Call that template.php

Then in your controller you'd do something like this:

```
public function welcome()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'welcome';
    $data['title']='Welcome to REfficient.com!';
    $data['sidebar_content'] = 'sidebar/no_sidebar';
    $data['additionalHeadInfo'] ='';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

So if you look at the template file the first line is loading the header and including the title variable to insert into the page (header, sidebar, maincontent and footer are all their own separate PHP pages) and so on.

Now what I did (since my layout was very similar to yours) is my main sidebar file has an if statement that says if logged in show x, if not show login form.

Note - the additionalHeadInfo variable is so I can have includes like jQueryUI or something on an individual page without loading it on pages that don't need it.

Comment: I am doing exactly same as you say. I am doing template system but one thing is disturbing me is that on right side I have some dynamic content that are changing and some content are changing after some time period with ajax file.
so if I pass parameter in every function like you have passed in welcome function I cannot access that right side bar to work properly

Comment: may be my information is ambiguous but basically I am facing a very strange problem that I need to be handled in short time

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever you couldn't change the content of the sidebar with AJAX after loading the page, I do it quite regularly. Just make sure your sidebar is set up with proper selectors so the content is easily accessed from jQuery (or plain js). I'm not sure I am seeing the issue.

Comment: I can't explain you clearly or you can't understand my problem until you view my code.Is there a way so that you can overview it?